# R data.table apply increasing values to specific row indices

Tags: r, data.table, row, difference

My data is like this:

```
Time  |    State   |   Event
01    |    0       |        
02    |    0       |        
03    |    0       |        
04    |    2       |   A_start
05    |    2       |          
06    |    2       |          
07    |    2       |          
08    |    2       |          
09    |    1       |   A_end  
10    |    1       |          
11    |    1       |          
12    |    1       |          
13    |    1       |          
14    |    2       |   B_start
15    |    2       |          
16    |    2       |          
17    |    2       |          
18    |    2       |          
19    |    0       |   B_end  
20    |    0       |          
21    |    0       |          
22    |    0       |          
23    |    0       |          
24    |    2       |   A_start
25    |    2       |          
26    |    2       |          
27    |    2       |          
28    |    2       |          
29    |    2       |          
30    |    2       |          
31    |    1       |   A_end  
32    |    1       |          
33    |    1       |          
34    |    1       |          
35    |    1       |          
36    |    1       |          
37    |    2       |   B_start
38    |    2       |          
39    |    2       |          
40    |    2       |
```

The cycle can repeat with any number of 0s, 1s and 2s in between. Sometimes, 0s, 1s or 2s can be missing entirely. I want to get the difference in the `Time` column between every `A_start` and the `A_end` immediately after it. Similarly, I want the difference in `Time` between every `B_start` and the `B_end` that immediately follows.

For this, I thought it would help if I made a "group" for each cycle, as follows:

```
Time  |    State   |   Event     |   Group
01    |    0       |             |
02    |    0       |             |
03    |    0       |             |
04    |    2       |   A_start   |   1
05    |    2       |             |
06    |    2       |             |
07    |    2       |             |
08    |    2       |             |
09    |    1       |   A_end     |   1
10    |    1       |             |
11    |    1       |             |
12    |    1       |             |
13    |    1       |             |
14    |    2       |   B_start   |   1
15    |    2       |             |
16    |    2       |             |
17    |    2       |             |
18    |    2       |             |
19    |    0       |   B_end     |   1
20    |    0       |             |
21    |    0       |             |
22    |    0       |             |
23    |    0       |             |
24    |    2       |   A_start   |   2
25    |    2       |             |
26    |    2       |             |
27    |    2       |             |
28    |    2       |             |
29    |    2       |             |
30    |    2       |             |
31    |    1       |   A_end     |   2
32    |    1       |             |
33    |    1       |             |
34    |    1       |             |
35    |    1       |             |
36    |    1       |             |
37    |    2       |   B_start   |   2
38    |    2       |             |
39    |    2       |             |
40    |    2       |             |
```

However, because there are sometimes missing values in the `State` column, this isn't working out too well.

The correct cycle sequence is `0 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2 -> 0`. Sometimes, a cycle may miss a 2 and be like this: `0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 0`. Various combinations of the cycle `0 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2 -> 0` are possible (44 in total). How should I go about this?

Comment: I didn't get what the next cycle should be. Maybe also show the next cycle, not clear (to me at least) what you want to do  .

Comment: @R.Prost updated

Comment: do you need to create the Event column also? or is it already in your dataset?

Comment: I've created the Event column, but for this case, you can assume it's already in the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base solution:

```
#identify the times where there is a change in the State
timeWithChanges <- which(abs(diff(dat$State)) > 0) + 1

#pivot those times into a m * 2 matrix
startEnd <- matrix(dat$Time[timeWithChanges], ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)

#calculate the time difference and label them as A, B
data.frame(AB=rep(c("A", "B"), nrow(startEnd)/2), 
    TimeDiff=startEnd[,2] - startEnd[,1])
```

Please let me know if this works generally enough for you.

data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="Time  |    State
01    |    0
02    |    0
03    |    0
04    |    2
05    |    2
06    |    2
07    |    2
08    |    2
09    |    1
10    |    1
11    |    1
12    |    1
13    |    1
14    |    2
15    |    2
16    |    2
17    |    2
18    |    2
19    |    0
20    |    0
21    |    0
22    |    0
23    |    0
24    |    2
25    |    2
26    |    2
27    |    2
28    |    2
29    |    2
30    |    2
31    |    1
32    |    1
33    |    1
34    |    1
35    |    1
36    |    1
37    |    2
38    |    2
39    |    2
40    |    2
41    |    0", sep="|", header=TRUE)
```